# The standard procedure to replace a user account with another

Tags: debian, security

How is the standard procedure to replace a user account with another i.e. delete a user and create another new one ?

its need arises as one person is to sell a laptop to another in which the installed Linux there is always the base OS

please elaborate answer to the very useful points of today IT security tech

Comment: This entirely depends on your requirements. Do you need to prevent the new user from restoring the old users files?

Comment: From a security point of view, if you were the buyer, would you trust the used OS installation? I wouldn't, and I would make sure to repartition and reinstall from scratch. Simply don't sell your laptop with a used OS on it. A buyer would never be certain you didn't install keyloggers or other intrusive software. From the buyer's point of view, the laptop is a compromised system.

Answer (score 1):

A standard procedure would be to wipe the system.

You could install a new copy of the OS for the buyer, in case they weren't sufficiently technically minded, but I for sure would prefer to install it myself from scratch anyway.